# Jquery Stop showing Hide elements

Tags: jquery

Jquery showing Hide elements for mil second. How to stop that. I tried display: none. I also give the same output.

my sample code:

```
if(data[0].video){
   $('#video').append('<div class="video-area">'+
             '<div id="player" data-plyr-provider="vimeo" data-plyr-embed-id="126777001"></div>'+
              '</div>');
}
else{
  $('#video').hide();

}
```

Comment: Add html part as well it will help bit more, my suggestion is put css property `display:none` in `#video` tag.

Comment: Whenever you change (hide) anything via js, you'll always get the FOUC - Flash Of Unstyled Content - it will be longer the more js you have to to be parsed, but will always be there.  You can reduce it eg by putting all js in the `<head>` but that increases user-visible load times.  The only option you have is to style it via HTML/CSS (either `style='display:none;'` in the element or `#video { display:none; }` in the css).

Answer (score 0):

The right choice in my opinion is to set `$('#video').hide();` at the loading of the page and simply display it if data[0].video == true